# Avoiding Repeated seed generation using srand()

Tags: c, algorithm, random, srand

I have a typical situation where I need to generate a batch of random numbers. I have used a loop which generates 100 random numbers on each pass:

```
for(int i=0; i<npasses; i++)
{
   srand(time(NULL)); //Initialize seed

   for(int j=0; j<100; j++)
      printf("%d ", rand()%10);

   printf("\n"); //New line after 100 numbers
}
```

Now, the inner loop executes in less than a millisecond. As a result, there is no change in the value of time(). This re-initializes the seed (srand()) to the same value and my random numbers are REPEATED..

Can anyone suggest a workaround/fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the seed once, before the loop.

Answer (score 5):

Keep `srand` out:

```
srand(time(NULL)); //Initialize seed
for(int i=0; i<npasses; i++)
{
   for(int j=0; j<100; j++)
      printf("%d ", rand()%10);

   printf("\n"); //New line after 100 numbers
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
srand(clock()); //Initialize seed
```

Comment: I think it will cause the same problem?

Comment: @AshisKumarSahoo I think it should not the same.

Comment: Why not? The system time cannot be caliberated below millisecond. time() is doing that already. I do not think that clock() works otherwise. Please clarify.

Comment: @AshisKumarSahoo The return value of () time is in seconds, but the value returned the clock () is usually microseconds since the system was started.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY.. I do not think so. Please cite some reference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30055/discussion-between-ashis-kumar-sahoo-and-bluepixy)

Comment: I do not want to use the time to do that

Comment: @BLUEPIXY.. I am sorry to say this -  but please revise your facts. The clock ticks are in the order of milliseconds. This is becauase CLOCKS_PER_SEC (or clock_t) has a typical value of around 1000. It essentially means that this timer is updated after every millisecond. And that defeats the purpose of my use. Anyways, I've found the answer. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: It differs by the processing system. Whether First, if you determine it after try actually. I said `"try this"`.

Comment: see because there is a commentary on "C A Reference Manual 5th edition".

Answer (score -3):

You can use the random generator to generate a new seed.

For example:

```
srand((unsigned int)rand());
```

And use `srand(time(NULL))` only once before the loop. But as suggested in another answer, you might as well drop the whole `srand` inside the loop as well.

Comment: Not only is this unnecessary, it's dangerous. Most generators now have longer than 32-bit periods, and repeated re-seeding with a 32-bit seed limits you to using only the first few numbers of a limited number of sequences. Call srand() once, and only once, at the start of your program.